# PHP addition/subtraction of letters

Tags: php

I have the following test code:

```
<?php

$letter = 'A';
$letter++;
$letter++;

echo $letter.'<br>';  // C

$letter++;
$letter++;
$letter++;

echo $letter.'<br>';  // F

// how to add plus 3 letters
// so that 
// $letter + 3 => I
```

As shown here by using `$letter++` or `$letter--` I can go up or down a character. Is there a way I can do something like  `$letter + 3` so it adds up 3 letters.

I know I can make a function with a loop which will add a char by char and at the end I will get the result. But is there a better way?

Comment: Everyone is suggesting adding '3' but this doesn't work ! :)

Comment: Did anybody read the question at all?

Comment: Did OP google the question at all?

Comment: And did anybody (of those suggesting $l+3) actually take the five seconds to test the proposed solution? http://sscce.org/ works in both ways; please test such simple three-liners.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There might be better solutions but the fastest way I can think of is:

```
  // get ASCII code of first letter
$ascii = ord('A');

  // echo letter for +3
echo chr($ascii + 3);
```

keep in mind that you will get other symbols after Z

Comment: But keep in mind that this solution (as griessi already mentioned) is not identical to the $x++ approach. php's increment_string() function behaves like perl`s string increment, i.e. `$letter = 'Z'; echo ++$letter;` prints `AA`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
      $letter = ord('A')+3;
      echo chr($letter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this'll work:

```
$x = 'G';
$y = range('A','Z');
echo $y[array_search($x,$y)+3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but in case someone searches.  Create array of letters, needed letter as in spreadsheet.

```php
$alphabet = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M',..........'AY','AZ');
//add 36 to the letter A
$val = (array_search('A',$alphabet)) + 36;
echo $alphabet[$val]."<BR>";
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like any of these answers as they don't replicate the function of PHP. Below is probably the easiest way to replicate it.

```
function addLetters($letter,$lettersToAdd){
   for ($i=0;$i<$lettersToAdd;$i++){
      $letter++;
   }
   return $letter;
}

echo addLetters('G',4);
echo "\n";
echo addLetters('Z',4);
```

Gives
    K
    AD